# Show that the complex series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n}$ converges for $z=i$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to show that the complex series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n}$ converges for $z=i$. I have worked out in a separate part of the problem that the radius of convergence is $1$, but now I am trying to show it by substituting in $i$ as follows:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{i^n}{n}=\frac{i}{1}-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{i}{5}-\frac{1}{6}-\frac{i}{7}+\frac{1}{8}+...$

$=\left(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{8}+...\right)+i\left(1-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}+...\right)$

Here's where I get stuck. I know that  by splitting a summation into real and imaginary parts, if we can show that the real part converges and that the imaginary part converges, the complex series converges. So, assuming that nothing has gone wrong in my thinking up to this point, I need to somehow show that both of the above parts converge. How would I go about doing this, and what would the parts converge to?

Comment: Alternating Series Test?

Answer (score 3):

Notice that the first sum is just $-\frac{1}{2}$ times the alternating harmonic series which is equal to $log2$ as the expansion of $log(x+1)$. The second part is equal to $\frac{\pi}{4}$ and is known as the Leibniz series.(It is the Taylor expansion of the $arctan(x)$ function for $x=1$)

Comment: The first sum is not $-\frac{1}{2}$ times the first sum, it is $-\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}-\cdots$, which can be shown, using the Taylor expansion of $\log{1+x}$, to be $-\frac{1}{2}\log{2}$.

Comment: @JoDraX indeed thank you for noticing!

Comment: The problem is to show the series converges.  Which is much easier than finding what it converges to.